# How to change the average with respect a random variable to another

Tags: probability, random-variables

Le $X$ be a standard normally distributed random variable
with PDF $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}.$$
The Q-function is defined as $$ Q(m)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{m}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx.$$
Let $Y$ a RV with PDF $f_Y(y)$ and CDF $F_Y(y)$.
Let $a$ and $b$ two constant and defin $$P=aQ(\sqrt{by}).$$
We want to avrage $P$ about $Y$ so 
$$Z=E_y\{aQ(\sqrt{by})\}.$$ 
I found the simplification in 4 steps, but i did not understand step 2 and how we go from step 2 to 3 and  4$E_y\{\}$ to $E_x$. This are the steps
\begin{align}
(1).Z&=E_y\{aQ(\sqrt{by})\}\\
(2).Z&=aE_y\{P(X > \sqrt{by}) \}\\
(3).Z&=aE_x\{P(y < \frac{x^2}{b})\}\\
(4).Z&=aE_x\{F_y(\frac{x^2}{b})\}
\end{align}

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Where you wrote $P = aQ(\sqrt{by}),$ I wonder if you meant $P = aQ(\sqrt{bY}),$ i.e. whether you intended $P$ to be a random variable. Then I'm guessing that you mean $Z = \operatorname E(aQ(\sqrt{bY})).$ Earlier you used lower-case $y$ as the argument to the p.d.f. and c.d.f. of (capital) $Y.$ And if $E$ is supposed to mean expectation, then you shouldn't have that subscript on it.

Comment: Hi $E_y$ is expectation i will ad figure.